# middleware order confusion over an express application

Tags: express, session, middleware

I have these middlewares in the yelp app in this order (assuming order matters):

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);

app.use('/campGrounds', campGroundRouter);

app.use('/campGrounds/:id/reviews', reviewRouter);

app.use(express.static('public'))

const sessionConfig = {

  secret: 'thisshouldfbeabettersecret',

  resave: false,

  saveUninitialized: true,

  cookie: {

    httpOnly: true,

    expires: Date.now() + 1000*60*60*24*7,

    maxAge: 1000*60*60*24*7

  }

};

app.use(session(sessionConfig));

app.use(flash());
```

when sending a request, the req goes through all these middlewares in order (since its app.use works for all req methods), until a response is sent and the req-res cycle ends.

when i make a req to : "http://localhost:3000/campGrounds/" the req goes through all these first:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
```

and then continues to :

```
app.use('/campGrounds', campGroundRouter);
```

the router then handles it to  this middleware in it:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {

   try {

     const allCamps = await Camp.find({});

     res.render('campGround/index', {allCamps})

   } catch (err) {

     next(err);

   }

})
```

and ends the req-res cycle with the res.render().

my question:

does this mean that the req that came in never reached to these middleware:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))

const sessionConfig = {

  secret: 'thisshouldfbeabettersecret',

  resave: false,

  saveUninitialized: true,

  cookie: {

    httpOnly: true,

    expires: Date.now() + 1000*60*60*24*7,

    maxAge: 1000*60*60*24*7

  }

};

app.use(session(sessionConfig));

app.use(flash());
```

and i have not created a session for the incoming request?

if yes, then why when i check my cookies i get a cookie with a "connect.sid" name and a value that is signed?